# Unique product ID for in-app billing resp. Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-console

In Google Play Console, you have to set product identifiers for managed products as well as subscriptions. Must those identifiers be unique across the entire app store resp. publisher account? Or only within the app bundle? Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a product ID into the Google Play console for a product/subscription, this id will be unique accross he entire app store resp per app / package name. publisher account. Moreover, according to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504)

> Product IDs need to be unique for your app, and they can’t be changed or reused after they’ve been created.

Hope it's help.

Comment: Hi Cochi, 

Thank you for your response. That's how I also thought. 

But the description says "unique for your app" and not "unique accross the entire app store/publisher account"

Yesterday, I was able to create another app in Google Play Console with different app identifier, but with exactly the same in-app billing items (same product identifiers) that are already used for another app.

So... that's my confusion. And I am asking myself whether this configuration would work as soon as the new app would be published.

Comment: Hi, sorry i  had misunderstood the question.
The product id is link to your app / package name, same identifier in two different app will work because they doesn't have the same package name. But the product id stay unique across the app lifetime on the store, not just the "app bundle".